# Hard upgrade of PostGIS - no postgis_restore in Ubuntu package

Tags: postgis, postgresql-14

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04 with Postgresql 14 and PostGIS 3.4 installed from the repositories.  I'm trying to follow the [steps](https://postgis.net/docs/postgis_administration.html#hard_upgrade) in the PostGIS docs for a hard upgrade of an old database dump.  Step three says...

```
postgis_restore "/somepath/olddb.backup" | psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres newdb 2> errors.txt
```

...however, postgis_restore is nowhere to be found on my system.  Shouldn't this have been installed with the PostGIS package?  Is this a packaging problem or am I missing something?

Comment: It is pg_restore - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgrestore.html

Comment: @TimothyDalton my understanding is that postgis_restore calls pg_restore after handling a bunch of PostGIS specific stuff.  Running pg_restore alone on my dumps fails.

Comment: I see. I am not sure if this is installed by default. Does this thead help you to inspect if it is on your filesystem? https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/ticket/4782